Quantum field theory in 2 spacetime dimensions
I have a question. Let us consider a two dimensional disc of finite radius as our spacetime. In a very simple case, we take a $\phi^3$ massless scalar field theory.
Consider a tree-level scattering of one particle (with momentum $k_1$) scattering into two (with momenta $k_2, k_3$).

The contribution to the amplitude would be
$$ \int e^{i(k_1 - k_2 - k_3).x}d^2x = \delta(k_1 - k_2 - k_3)$$
which is the statement of momentum conservation when $x$ is integrated all over spacetime.
Taking a diversion:
The usage of the Euclidean Green function is as follows: we have the value of the field in the boundary (the circumference of the circle) and with the help of this and the Green's function, we can find the solution of the Klein Gordon field equation at the desired bulk point.
Now for a disc, in Euclidean coordinates, the two-point Green's function is:
$$\frac{1-r^2}{r^2+1-2r \cos(\theta-\alpha)}$$
(from Classical Electrodynamics by J.Jackson)
where $\theta$ is the bulk angle and $\alpha$ is the boundary angle and $r$ is the radial coordinate.
The two point function above becomes singular at $r=1$ for every $\theta = \alpha$ (that is, when the bulk angle of interest is the same as that of the boundary).
Back to the question:
Does this mean that we cannot integrate the $x$ (and thus $r$) in the scattering amplitude factor written above all over the disc (we must leave the boundary)? Taking the radius of the disc to infinity, and thus generalising to infinite two dimensional space, is it correct that we can't integrate $x$ at infinity?
This seems to violate momentum conservation which clearly indicates a mistake.
Please help me understand what is the mistake here.
[Even though we have considered a one to two scattering, I think that a singularity in the two point Green's function occuring somewhere means that it is a forbidden region for any scattering process.]

I'm very confused what the different sections here have to do with each other. You first consider 1->2 scattering of some unspecified particle. Then you talk about the two-point function (which is the propagator, i.e. 1->1 scattering, and again you have not specified what kind of field we're looking at), write down an expression "for a disc" without any reference or explaining what the "bulk angle" or "boundary angle" mean (or what $r$ is), then we unmotivatedly talking about the Rindler metric. Then you claim we "cannot integrate the x" but there is no x in the propagator.

Please keep in mind that people have only the context you put in your question, and, when in doubt, rather overexplain rather than underexplain what exactly you're doing.

I'll edit the question... I'll explain more clearly in some time

Still: What are the two angles and the $r$ in your Green's function? Are you sure this is really the kind of "Green's function" you have to use in this case? QFT "Green's functions" are usually written in momentum space and have to be computed with the Feynman prescription for avoiding poles, while anything you have copied from a classical EM book is probably an advanced or retarded Green's function.

Okay I understand where the mistake is. I'll try to get more clarity by reading more. But I'll let the question be, in case I receive any more valuable help or corrections.
